# Identify WebElements with unique identifiers

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need help on the elements identification.

```
Login : http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/
uname : admin@yourstore.com
pass : admin

Click > Catalog > Categories > Add New
```

I am facing difficulty in identifying the xpaths for the below as there are no unique identifiers.

```
xpath to select value for limited to customer roles 
xpath to select value for limited to store
```

Your explanation will help me to learn how to write xpaths for webelements where there are no unique identifiers.

limited to customer roles

```
<div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" unselectable="on">
<ul id="SelectedCustomerRoleIds_taglist" class="k-reset" unselectable="on" role="listbox"/>
<input class="k-input k-readonly" style="width: 25px" accesskey="" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="SelectedCustomerRoleIds_taglist SelectedCustomerRoleIds_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false"/>
<span class="k-icon k-loading k-loading-hidden"/>
</div>

<select id="SelectedCustomerRoleIds" name="SelectedCustomerRoleIds" multiple="multiple" data-role="multiselect" style="display: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
<option value="1">Administrators</option>
<option value="2">Forum Moderators</option>
<option value="4">Guests</option>
<option value="3">Registered</option>
<option value="5">Vendors</option>
</select>
```

limited to store

```
<div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" unselectable="on">
<ul id="SelectedStoreIds_taglist" class="k-reset" unselectable="on" role="listbox"/>
<input class="k-input k-readonly" style="width: 25px" accesskey="" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="SelectedStoreIds_taglist SelectedStoreIds_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false"/>
<span class="k-icon k-loading k-loading-hidden"/>
</div>

<select id="SelectedStoreIds" name="SelectedStoreIds" multiple="multiple" data-role="multiselect" style="display: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
<option value="1">nopCommerce demo store</option>
<option value="2">Sample store 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you share HTML here??

Comment: Added the html's in my post.

Comment: Why are you going to xpath here if you can simply locate it by using `id`??

Comment: Try `driver.findElement(By.id("SelectedCustomerRoleIds"))` for customers role

Comment: And `driver.findElement(By.id("SelectedStoreIds"))` for limited to store

Comment: //select[@id='SelectedCustomerRoleIds'] and //select[@id='SelectedStoreIds'] are not helping - so that's why I am not able to get the proper xpaths. If you can try login to the application then it will help you to see the issue.

Comment: But these elements are hidden, so could tell me when it's getting visible??

Comment: And why provided xPath not helping?? Is there any exception??

Comment: Is customer role dropdown getting visible when you click on ul element with this I'd `SelectedCustomerRoleIds_taglist`

Comment: I'm sorry but this time I can't login into your application but here if you share all information abouty question, I will definitely solve your problem..:)

Comment: click at .//*[@id='tab-info']/div/div/div/div[12]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div for limited for customer roles shows the options present in the select tags

click at .//*[@id='tab-info']/div/div/div/div[13]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div for limited to stores shows the options present in the select tags

but since these xpaths are not reliable, i need help in forming the correct xpaths

Comment: Ok tell me which programming language are you using??

Comment: Selenium with Java :) and I am learning to write xpaths for webelements. Basically I am from testing background.

Comment: Ok try provided answer and let me know...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
```

- For customers role dropdown :-

  ```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("SelectedCustomerRoleIds_taglist"))).click();

  Select customers = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SelectedCustomerRoleIds_taglist"))));
  customers.selectByVisibleText("Administrators");
  ```
- For limited  to store dropdown :-

  ```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("SelectedStoreIds_taglist"))).click();

  Select store = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SelectedStoreIds"))));
  store.selectByVisibleText("nopCommerce demo store");
  ```